# Issue Mocking Function Invoked by Event with QUnit and Sinon

Tags: jquery, mocking, qunit, sinon

My goal is to mock the runProcedure function and check that it was called after the user clicks. However, the test continues to fail even though it can clearly be seen that the runProcedure function is called once the user clicks the page and if the miniWindowShowing variable is `false`, which it is when the page loads. Can anyone explain how to use QUnit with sinon to accomplish this goal? Below is the code I am working with.

QUnit HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Function Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-1.7.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sinonjs.org/releases/sinon-qunit-0.8.0.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="Function Source.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="TestSuite.js"></script>
  <script>
    test( "Test Click Calls Function", testClickCallsFunction);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript Test File

```
// Test that when user clicks on the page, a function is called
function testClickCallsFunction(){

    var event = $.Event("click");   
    var funcSpy = sinon.spy(runProcedure);
    $(document).trigger(event);

    ok(funcSpy.called);
}
```

JavaScript Functions to Test

```
var miniWindowShowing = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(this).click(function (e) {
        //Ignore input events if the mini window is showing
        if(!miniWindowShowing)
        {
            runProcedure();         
        }
    });

})

function runProcedure() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minor issue with your way creating the spy. `sinon.spy(runProcedure)` creates a new spy with the passed function, but it don't replace the original function with that spy. So when you call `runProcedure` its still the original function. To overwrite the function with the spy you have to use this syntax:  `sinon.spy(window, 'runProcedure')`, which will replace the function `runProcedure` in the global namespace with the spy.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but when I do that, I get the following error: `Attempted to wrap undefined property function runProcedure(){} as function`.

`var funcSpy = sinon.spy( window, runProcedure)` is the new line;

Comment: Do you miss the `''` around `runProcedure`? or is this just in the error message?